# UIPrintInteractionController Translucent Bar Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uiprintinteractioncntrler

[image]
UIPrintInteractionController when presented in iPhone as modal view, then i get translucent bar on top. I want it to be opaque so that background view's navigation bar is not visible. Refer screen-shot for better clarification.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: By default, it is an opaque bar. You should post some code, which you think can create this problem. Are you able to push cancel button of `UIPrintInteractionController`? Does that dismiss it?

Comment: @viral: By default its opaque, but our application has translucent bar for navigation controller. So that printview bar appears translucent.

Comment: @iNeo how did you create the opaque bar for you application? It should exclude any navigationbars that are not part of you application.

Answer (score 0):

when you about to present the modal view from parent viewcontroller hide the navigationbar and when modal view is dismissed make the navigationbar as unhidden.

Comment: While I agree that your answer will solve the problem, I think of it as NOT Proper approach.

Comment: @vrk: Your solution gives a black bar at top. While i needed the default blue style bar.

Answer (score 0):

As you have still not posted any code, answer can't be exact.

But, You can try change the appearance for your navigation bar through out the application.

May be this can help you achieve that: (put it right after you `alloc/init` your `navigationcontroller` in `AppDelegate.m`)

```
if ([UINavigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(appearance)]) 
{   
    // For iOS 5.0 and above
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];
    // Black Opaque or whatever your choice is
} 
else 
{   
    // For iOS below 5.0
    self.navController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    // Black Opaque or whatever your choice is
}
```

Let me know results, once you apply this.

Comment: In our application, we have translucent navigation bar throughout the application. But for this print screen we needed it to be opaque.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this six years later, in iOS 11! I had to add this:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO]
```

I'm not setting the navigation bar to translucent anywhere in my app, but I guess that's the default now?

If you want to use translucent navigation bars elsewhere in your app, I think you could implement `UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate` and use `printInteractionControllerWillDismissPrinterOptions` to set translucent back to YES again when the popup closes.